# lambda function to scale column in pandas dataframe returns: "'float' object has no attribute 'min'"

Tags: python, pandas

I am just getting started in Python and Machine Learning and have encountered an issue which I haven't been able to fix myself or with any other online resource.
I am trying to scale a column in a pandas dataframe using a lambda function in the following way:

```
X['col1'] = X['col1'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```

and get the following error message:

> 'float' object has no attribute 'min'

I have tried to convert the data type into integer and the following error is returned:

> 'int' object has no attribute 'min'

I believe I am getting something pretty basic wrong, hope anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can give a try to `MinMaxScaler` under `Scikit-Learn`. Check 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think apply here is not necessary, because exist faster vectorized solution - change `x` to column `X['col1']`:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [100,10,1,20,10,-20,200]})
X['col2'] = (X['col1'] - X['col1'].min()) / (X['col1'].max() - X['col1'].min())
print (X)

   col1      col2
0   100  0.545455
1    10  0.136364
2     1  0.095455
3    20  0.181818
4    10  0.136364
5   -20  0.000000
6   200  1.000000
```

Like @meW pointed in comments another solution is use [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html):

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X['col2'] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X[['col1']])
print (X)

   col1      col2
0   100  0.545455
1    10  0.136364
2     1  0.095455
3    20  0.181818
4    10  0.136364
5   -20  0.000000
6   200  1.000000
```

Comment: Just tried it and it works thanks. In fact I was trying to implement the lambda function to verify that I had used the MinMaxScaler correctly. Results match up

Answer (score 0):

## Check below code !

@ if condition is required for `.apply(--if--else,axis=0/1) !`

@ else use `assign` method, it will also give same result !

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'salary':[10,29,76,54,32]})

df.apply(lambda x: ((x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())) if x.name == 'salary' else x, axis=0)

df.assign(salary=lambda x: ((x['salary']-x['salary'].min() )/(x['salary'].max()-x['salary'].min()) ))
```