# scaling only numeric values in data frame that contain string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

i am in python , i am try to make scaling to data frame

```
subject_id hour_measure         urinecolor   blood pressure                  
3          1.00                 red          40
           1.15                 red          high
4          2.00              yellow          low
```

as it that contain numeric and text columns 
the following code gives me error

```
 #MinMaxScaler for Data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

it gives me error as the data frame contain string , how can i tell python to only scale columns contain numbers , and also scale numeric values in string columns .

Comment: Do you want to scale the numbers in the mixed columns - like "blood pressure" or only in the numeric columns? If it is just the numeric columns you could just subset these e.g. `X[['hour_meassure',...]] =  scaler.fit_transform(['hour_meassure',...])`

Comment: i want to scale all numeric columns , and also numeric values in string columns (e.g  blood pressure in the attached example)

Comment: also email was sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert non numeric values to missing values and then use [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087038/2901002) for scaling, last replace missing values back to original:

```
print (df)
   subject_id  hour_measure urinecolor blood pressure
0           3          1.00        red             40
1           3          1.15        red           high
2           4          2.00     yellow            low
3           5          5.00     yellow            100

df = df.set_index('subject_id')

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
df2 = (df1 - df1.min()) / (df1.max() - df1.min())

df = df2.combine_first(df)
print (df)
            hour_measure urinecolor blood pressure
subject_id                                        
3                 0.0000        red              0
3                 0.0375        red           high
4                 0.2500     yellow            low
5                 1.0000     yellow              1
```

---

**First solution**:

I suggest replace text columns to numeric by dictionary like:

```
dbp = {'high': 150, 'low': 60}

df['blood pressure'] = df['blood pressure'].replace(dbp)
```

All together:

```
#if subject_id are numeric convert them to index
df = df.set_index('subject_id')

dbp = {'high': 150, 'low': 60}
#replace to numbers and convert to integers
df['blood pressure'] = df['blood pressure'].replace(dbp).astype(int)

print (df)
            hour_measure urinecolor  blood pressure
subject_id                                         
3                   1.00        red              40
3                   1.15        red             150
4                   2.00     yellow              60

print (df.dtypes)
hour_measure      float64
urinecolor         object
blood pressure      int32
dtype: object
```

---

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))
#select only numeric columns
X = scaler.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes(np.number))
print (X)
[[0.         0.        ]
 [0.15       1.        ]
 [1.         0.18181818]]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.select_dtypes(np.number))
            hour_measure  blood pressure
subject_id                              
3                   1.00              40
3                   1.15             150
4                   2.00              60
```

Comment: thank you for your concern and time . but there is no solution to scale only numeric values in string columns

Comment: @Nora - Possible, but solution is completely changed.

Comment: kindly, if you don't mind to add the previous solution also to the answer to test both solution

Comment: in the solution that you make scale manually, i don't want to scale  the hour_measure column , how can i remove it from scaling

Comment: @Nora for scaling between `0 and 52` use `min1 = 0
max1 = 52
df2 = (df1 - df1.min()) / (df1.max() - df1.min())
df2 = df2 * (max1 - min1) + min1`

Comment: i try to make the index the both columns in your solution *df = data.set_index(['subject_id','hour_measure'])

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
df2 = (df1 - df1.min()) / (df1.max() - df1.min())

df = df2.combine_first(df)*

Answer (score 0):

Another approach as following: (I've added new row the see scaled values in blood pressure)

```
       hour_measure urinecolor blood pressure  temp_column
0          1.00        red             40           40
1          1.15        red           high            0
2          2.00     yellow            low            0
3          3.00     yellow             20           20

df['temp_column'] = df['blood pressure'].values
df['temp_column'] = df['temp_column'].apply(lambda x: 0 if str(x).isalpha() == True else x)
```

This will create a new temp_column with the numeric values of blood pressure column.

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))
df['hour_measure'] = scaler.fit_transform(df['hour_measure'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
df['temp_column'] = scaler.fit_transform(df['temp_column'].values.reshape(-1 ,1))
```

I've applied MinMaxScaler to temp_column which contains numeric values of blood pressure. And i just put scaled numeric values to back in blood pressure column.

```
numeric_rows = pd.to_numeric(df['blood pressure'], errors='coerce').dropna().index.tolist()
print('Index of numeric values in blood pressure column: ', numeric_rows)
for i in numeric_rows:
    df['blood pressure'].iloc[i] = df['temp_column'].iloc[i]
df = df.drop(['temp_column'], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   hour_measure urinecolor blood pressure
0         0.000        red              1
1         0.075        red           high
2         0.500     yellow            low
3         1.000     yellow            0.5
```